How can I change the col_width of a modelsummary table (using "gt")?
I just want to change the "vaiable" column of a modelsummary regression table, as I have long variable names and modelsummary automatically starts new "rows". I supply a list with class "modelsummary_list" to modelsummary. In this I name the variables in the colum "term". Using the package "gt" I want to format the first colum, the "term" colum to be wider.
Same problem with an example:
lm1 <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)

modsum <- modelsummary(lm1, output = "gt") %>% 
  cols_width( c("term") ~ px(200)) 

does not work: "Colum term doesn't exist"
How can I find out the name of the Variable column?

An examination of the modelsummary output shows what needs to be changed:
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(modelsummary))
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)

lm1 <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)

modsum <- modelsummary(lm1, output = "gt")
# modsum   # Uncomment to see original format

# Shows that first column in the first list element has single space as its header
#str(modsum)   # Uncomment to see list structure of output object
modsum[1]
#> $`_data`
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>    ` `           `(1)`   
#>    <chr>         <chr>   
#>  1 "(Intercept)" -17.579 
#>  2 ""            (6.758) 
#>  3 "speed"       3.932   
#>  4 ""            (0.416) 
#>  5 "Num.Obs."    50      
#>  6 "R2"          0.651   
#>  7 "R2 Adj."     0.644   
#>  8 "AIC"         419.2   
#>  9 "BIC"         424.9   
#> 10 "Log.Lik."    -206.578
#> 11 "RMSE"        15.07

modsum_new <- modelsummary(lm1, output = "gt") %>% 
  cols_width(starts_with(" ") ~ px(200))

# modsum_new   # Uncomment to see new, wider format

Created on 2024-05-12 with reprex v2.1.0
